# Not getting data in react app after successful socket connection

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, moleculer

I am trying to return some data to my react frontend from my moleculer backend upon connection over sockets. I am running into challenges in getting the data, and what's particularly confusing to me is, when I have an error on the backend, that full error gets returned over the socket to the front-end. But when I resolve the error, all I get on the front-end is `null`. I am unclear why I am getting a response in the error case, and a `null` response when there is no error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code on the backend. This function fires when the socket request for 'auth.register' comes in:

```
register(ctx) {
  const socketId = ctx.meta.socket.id;
  console.log('socketId: ', socketId);

  const response = {
    status: 'success',
    code: null,
    message: 'Device registered with version 1.0.0.',
    body: { socketId },
    broadcast: false,
    messageId: 'unknown',
    opts: {}
  }

  return response;
},
```

And this is my front-end socket call:

```
io.Socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log("Connection with the socket gateway established on socket");
  // register
  io.Socket.emit('call', 'auth.register', {
    key: config.key,
    version: `${config.app} ${config.version}`,
    app: config.app,
  }, (res) => {
    console.log('res: ', res);
  });
});
```

With the code like this, `res` in the console on the front-end is equal to `null`.

Now, if I change the backend code to have an error, like so:

```
register(ctx) {
  const socketId = ctx.meta.socket.id;
  console.log('socketId: ', socketId);

  response = {
    status: 'success',
    code: null,
    message: 'Device registered with version 1.0.0.',
    body: { socketId },
    broadcast: false,
    messageId: 'unknown',
    opts: {}
  }

  return response;
},
```

The full error gets returned over the socket, so in the front-end console, `res` is this:

```
{name: "ReferenceError", message: "response is not defined"}
```

I'm trying to understand why, if there is an error on the backend, that gets successfully returned in the callback of the socket call from the front-end, but if there is no error all I end up with is `null`.

What am I missing here? How can I return the data to the front-end in this situation?